# Does Appdome fuse increse the size of the binary than traditional integration?

Tags: security, mobile-application

Appdome seems to offer its own fusing technique to add security controls and embed SDKs in an automated way. Does the final binary size increase or decrease significantly than the traditional approach of embedding SDKs ?

What are the other benefits Appdome gives other than the easy wizard based approach to add/remove security controls

Comment: Did you get any where with this.
I have just been trawling their site and am wondering if it is suitable for my Android & IOS apps build with Xamarin in Visula studio (Windows & via tethered Mac)

Comment: Nope. There wasn't much response from the Appdome folks themselves and the customer i was working for this use-case later dropped the idea, so i didn't get a chance to further explore.

Comment: OK - thanks for getting back to me.
Out of curiosity - were you looking to cover Jailbreaks & Rooting?
If yes, did you find a solution that you could recommend.

Comment: one team i know uses https://www.onespan.com/products/application-shielding

Answer (score 1):

The size of the binary will depend on the security features added via Appdome. Appdome builds all features to be size efficient out of the box. It also uses a learning engine to generate the security code, so the system is constantly improving w/r/t file size and security methods. Appdome also offers several tools for the user to customize encryption and obfuscation. These tools allow a user to tailor the implementation for an optimized result (vs. traditional tools).

The main benefit of Appdome is speed and repeatability of security implementations. It's a no-code system that provides compatibility with all native and non-native apps (Xamarin, Cordova, React Native, included), very broad security offering including RASP, OWASP Top 10, file/pref/string encryption, dex-java class encryption, TLS enforcement, certificate pinning and client certs, OS integrity (jailbreak, rooting, FRIDA, etc.), mobile privacy (Keylogger, copy/paste, etc.), CI/CD integration, a dev framework for custom event handling on top of other SDKs services (such as SSO, MDM/EMM/MAM and more). All of Appdome security features are also self-defending, meaning they secure the app and the secure the security too (so, e.g., the obfuscation added via Appdome isn't undone). If you add SSO using Appdome, Appdome also automatically build secure credential stores, user workflows, etc., so you don't have to.

Full disclosure: I work at Appdome. This information is on the web at https://www.appdome.com (free trial available). File size information based on the 25K+ implementations we have done.